# Simple mapping of integer values to another integer

Tags: python

This is a *very* simple problem but I have not found an easy way to solve it. Consider the following sets of integers (these are not actual Python `set`s since they contain an infinite number of members):

```
set1 = (0, 3, 6, 9,  ...) --> 0
set2 = (1, 4, 7, 10, ...) --> 2
set3 = (2, 5, 8, 11, ...) --> 4
```

This is: assuming I receive a random positive integer as input, I need to map those that belong to `set1` to the integer `0`, those in `set2` to `2` and those in `set3` to `4`.

Is there an "easy" way to do this in Python?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: sets like these can be represented in calculations instead, making this a trivial task. Are the sets here a good representation of what you're looking for?

Comment: What are you using, lists, np.arrays...?

Comment: @DeveshKumarSingh I've tried ways of using the floor division operator `//` to solve it, but could not figure out how to take advantage of it. @Paritosh: I'm not using actual sets, as I state in the question. @yatu: neither, I get a random integer as input I I need to map it to another integer according to which "set" it belongs to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
def map_to_set(i):
    return 2*(i%3)
```